# Is the sequence $(-1)^n$ eventually or frequently in the set {$1$}

Tags: real-analysis

This is what I know:

A sequence $(a_{n})$ is eventually in a set $A \subseteq \mathbb{R} $ if there exists an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $a_{n} \in A $ $\forall n \geq N$

A sequence $(a_{n})$ is frequently in a set $A \subseteq \mathbb{R} $ if  for every $N \in \mathbb{N}$ there exists $n \geq N $ such that $a_{n} \in A$

I cannot think of a way to find an $N$ for which the sequence converges from that point on to just {$1$}, so it is not eventually in {$1$}. But is it frequently in {$1$}? How would I go about showing that?

Also, does frequently imply eventually, or does eventually imply frequently? I can't see how one could imply the other, I would appreciate guidance on this.

Comment: So you want to figure out whether, for every $N\in\mathbb N,$ there exists $n\ge N$ such that $(-1)^n\in\{1\}$, i.e., such that $(-1)^n=1$? Have you tried any examples? Can you fin $n\ge1$ such that $(-1)^n=1$? Can you find $n\ge10$ such that $(-1)^n=1$? How about $n\ge100$?

Comment: "$a_n$ is eventually in $A$" means that if you go far enough out in the sequence, then _all terms_ in the sequence from there on out are contained in $A$. "$a_n$ is frequently in $A$" means that no matter how far out in the sequence you go, you can still find terms that are in $A$. So "frequently in $A$" and "eventually in $A^c$" (the complement of $A$) are complementary events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct, it is not eventually in {1}.

Yes, it's frequently in the set {1}.
Just pick any $N$. Now look at two cases: N even and N odd.
If N is even pick n=N, otherwise pick n=N+1.

Eventually implies frequently. You should be able to prove it easily,
just use the two definitions to prove this.

Comment: I was thinking along those lines. I did realize that the even exponents are always $1$ and it had to be frequently in {$1$}, I just wasn't sure about my reasoning.